# Multiple Conditions in combinatoric question

Tags: combinatorics

There are 12 identical white balls, and 4 identical black balls.
You want to order them in a line of length 16, in a way that between every couple of black balls, there are at least 2 white balls.
Also, you can't have balls of the same color in the two edges of the line. (For instance, you can't have white in the right edge and white in the left edge, and the same for black).
How many orders exist that suffice the conditions?

I tried to solve it this way:

Put 4 black balls like this:

b b b b

Put 2 whites between each two, and 1 white in one of the edges:

w b ww b ww b ww b

and now count the number of options to put 5 in one of the edges, and next to each one of the three 'ww'.
Then multiply the result by two, to also count the other edge.

I got this:
$4+5-1\choose5$$*2$

Did I get it right? Is there an easier way to count it?

Comment: You speak of "couple of black balls". Does that mean two consecutive black balls? If not then why the word "couple"?

Comment: I don't see how you avoided having both the first and the final ball in the line be black.  Instead, begin as you had, prearranging balls as `bwwbwwbwwb` and then choose either left or right to place another white ball.  E.g. having placed on the left we now have `wbwwbwwbwwb`.  Now, placing the remaining five balls in the available groups, we count with stars and bars and complete the problem.  Your attempt was very close but neglected to account for the fact that we weren't guaranteed to pick one edge or the other.

Comment: @drhab between any two black balls in the line at least two white balls must appear between them, so `bwbwwwbwwwbwwwww` fails to be a valid arrangement because between the first two black balls appearing only one white ball appeared between.

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right, I forgot that I put 1 white ball in one of the edges

Comment: With that edit, I now agree with your answer.  Good work.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you! Is there a simpler method?